# Adapting With/CTE statement

Tags: sql-server, with-statement

Using SQL Server 2012.... This code works as a standalone script but I need the value returned within a `iif(...)` nested in a `Case...when` as part of a larger script:

```
with GroupedValues (Value, Frequency, SelectingCriteria) AS
(Select
    Table1.Cost as Value,
    Count(*) as Frequency,
Table2.AccountNumber as SelectingCriteria

from Table1, Table 2 
)

Group by Table1.Cost, Table2.AccountNumber) 

Select
    Max(Value) as Value
From GroupedValues a INNER JOIN
    (select Max(Frequency) AS MaxFrequency
     from GroupedValues) b
on a.Frequency=b.MaxFrequency
```

Comment: Is this your actual code?  This doesn't look like functioning code.

Comment: First get rid of the implict joins and join the 21st century!

Comment: Am I understanding you right, you'd like to put the above code inside an IIF which is then part of a CASE statement?

Comment: If I understand you correclty you need to use the results of teh CTE later in a script? Inthis case you cannot use a CTE, they can only be referred to in the statement immediately following the CTE. A temp table might be what you need or a table varaible.

Comment: It is functioning code, but the answer below works great as part of my nested situation.  I'm still a newbie so thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are just doing this:

```
select top 1 
  Value
from (
  select
    Table1.Cost, Table2.AccountNumber
    Count(*) as Frequency,
    Table1.Cost as Value
  from Table1 cross join Table2 
  group by Table1.Cost, Table2.AccountNumber, Table1.Cost 
) T
order by 
  Frequency desc, 
  Value desc
```

Comment: Do not perpetuate the use of implict joins which are a SQL antipattern

Comment: @HLGEM: It is a cross join, not an inner or outer join; the one and only circumstance in which I tolerate that syntax myself. You are preaching to the converted.

Comment: There is this really nice syntax called CROSS JOIN. It is clearer and easier to maintain. I especially would not put a CROSS JOIN in implicit syntax since maintainers will not know if it was meant as one or was a bug.

Comment: @FrankHoratio: You are welcome. The best thanks, of course, is a vote.